# How can I share a SharePoint subsite with a set of users?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I used this method to create a SharePoint subsite:-

http://sympmarc.com/2014/03/30/create-a-subsite-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-calls/

Using REST APIs, what is the simplest way to share this subsite with a set of users(email ids)?

Comment: is it online or onprem ?

Comment: I am creating an app and I want to create a subsite and configure it for users using REST API calls.

Comment: ok but is it SharePoint online(office 365) or SharePoint 2013 server (on premises) ?

Comment: SharePoint online(office 365)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the REST API to provide permissions to the subsite. SharePoint sends an automatic email to users saying "Welcome to SharePoint site...:

I have not tried using the REST API to provide permissions, but you can refer to the below link and see if it is helpful.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx

Edited the answer with another option. If requirement is to share subsite with email ids, we can send email to users via REST API(body can contain link to subsite).

Use this below function, please note that the email id should be present in SharePoint, it will not send email to external users who do not have permission to site(I think so).

```
    function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
//Get the relative url of the site
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
            },
            'From': from,
            'To': {
                'results': [to]
            },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Email Sent Successfully');
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: Which REST API should I exactly use?
My query is simple: I want to simply share a subsite with a set of users(email ids).

Comment: please refer edited answer...

Comment: I am actually looking for a REST API which will give permissions for a particulat subsite.

Comment: My query:

I have created a fresh subsite using REST API using this method:-

sympmarc.com/2014/03/30/create-a-subsite-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-calls/

I have set 'UseUniquePermissions': false.

So, currently no one has permissions to this subsite.

Now lets say I have two email ids: anonymous@example.com and example@anonymous.com

Which REST API should I use to share and give contribute permissions to this subsite to these two email ids?

Comment: i thought permission are already set/given to users, for giving permissions to user you can use code given by Gautam Sheth..... once permission is given you can send manual emails to users via code shared in my post...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to add users to site

```
'use strict';  

var hostweburl;  
var appweburl;  

 // Get the URLs for the app web the host web URL from the query string.  

$(document).ready(function () {  

    //Get the URI decoded URLs.  
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));  
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));  

    // Resources are in URLs in the form:  
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource  


    // Load the js file and continue to load the page with information about the folders.  
    // SP.RequestExecutor.js to make cross-domain requests  
    $.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js",userEmail);  
});  

function userEmail(){
    var userEmailArray = ['user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com','user1@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com','user2@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com']; //add users in this array
    for(var i=0;i<userEmailArray.length;i++){
        addNewuser(userEmailArray[i]);
    }
}

function addNewuser(email) {  
    var executor;     
     // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.  
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);  

    executor.executeAsync({  

    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Site Members')/users?@target='"+ hostweburl + "'",  //modify according to your group name
    method: "POST",  
    body:"{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName': 'i:0#.f|membership|"+email+"' }",  
    headers: {  
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",  
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
},  

success: function(data)    
        {    
            console.log("New User added successfully in SharePoint Group");    
        },    
        error: function(err)     
        {    
            console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));    
        }      });  
}  
//Utilities  
// Retrieve a query string value.  
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.  
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {  
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");  
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {  
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");  
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Should I create a group first before executing this line of code:-

url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Site Members')/users?@target='"+ hostweburl + "'",  //modify according to your group name

Comment: Yes the SharePoint group needs to created before you execute this code.

Comment: How will the solution be different for SharePoint 2013 server (on premises) ?

Additionally, I really need to understand the steps involved:-

I have simply followed the steps mentioned here and created a subsite:-

http://sympmarc.com/2014/03/30/create-a-subsite-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-calls/

To share this subsite with a couple of users(email ids), I need to create a SharePoint Group first?

If yes, how should I associate the group with the SharePoint Subsite?

Comment: As per your link , uniquePermissions: false , when this attribute is set, the new site created will inherit permissions from the parent site. So when you execute my code, you just need to enter the group name of parent site and then the user would be able to access site. So all users who have access to parent site, will have access to newly created site.

Comment: In case of OnPremise, its not much different if you are using provider hosted app, replace the variable as  var userEmailArray = ['domain\loginname']; 
However, it wouldn't make sense to user provider hosted app IMO to perform these operations

Comment: If I set uniquePermissions: true, how should I proceed?

Comment: go to this url: "https://siteurl/_layouts/15/user.aspx", here you will find list of groups created. Use the name of the group you want and add user in that group according to the above code i have written.

Comment: I could successfully create a group and add members to the group. How should I share the subsite created with this group?

Comment: by sharing , you mean , you want to email users ? Use the code provided by Siddharth Vaghasia to send mail after adding them to group.

Comment: I am not concerned about email. I have created a subsite and a group. How do I connect both of them. How can I give members of the group access to the subsite?